# angularjs service function invoke itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, service

I want to create a startService function in angularjs service (factory).
I want to startService function check if it can start service and if not it will invoke itself with a timeout and than checks again.

```
startService: function() {      
      if(!someComaprison) {
        $timeout(this.startService, 5000);
        return;
      }

      //starts service
    },
```

But in the next start of the function it crashes because this is undefined.
How to make such a loop in services? I have no problem doing it with controllers functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *context*(in this case-> `this`) too. Try like this:

```
$timeout(this.startService.bind(this), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to keep the right `this` context,you need to bind the function to this

```
$timeout(this.startService.bind(this), 5000);
```

or the function executed in the timeout will not know what `this` refers to.

have a look a the following article :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

EDIT : for the other issue :

```
var that = this;

this.startHttpRequest = function(userId) {
    var httpRequest = $http.post(somedata....);


    httpRequest.success(function(data){
      that.startHttpRequest(data.userId);
    });
  }
```

But, dont ask 2 different questions like that, or edit your first question instead of posting a question as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I have another problem like executing function after http request success:

this.startHttpRequest = function(userId) {
    var httpRequest = $http.post(somedata....);
    var that = this;

    httpRequest.success(function(data){
      that.startHttpRequest(data.userId);
    });
  }
and it normally works but after some time i have that === undefined. How to bind this with http request so I can avoid using that?